# WP plugin repository didn't parse readme.txt correctly

Tags: plugin-development

I just added a plugin on WP repository but it seems like my readme.txt wasn't parsed correctly. I even ran it through the validator but on the plugin page it shows `Description` text under all tabs - `Installation, Changelog, FAQ`

Plugin - http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/facebook-like-thumbnail/
Readme.txt - http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/facebook-like-thumbnail/tags/0.1/readme.txt

So did I do something wrong? Or readme file parser is to blame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a short piece of text above the description that will be the "short description". You may need a blank line above and below.

If it is not there, then the wp parser uses the first x characters of the description

like this

http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/amr-ical-events-list/trunk/readme.txt

http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/amr-ical-events-list/trunk/readme.txt

Comment: I believe it will take a little time to reflect too. Right? Here is my readme file now http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/facebook-like-thumbnail/trunk/readme.txt